# nativescript ui page is not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

nativescript app successfully deployed in the device but while clicking the login button it redirects to my login page but nothing will not displayed
what i have is:

login.component.ts

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'demo-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
```

login.component.tns.html

```
<StackLayout class="p-10">
<Image src="res://logo_login" stretch="none" 
horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
<TextField [(ngModel)]="email" [hint]="Email Address"    
 keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false"    
  autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
 <TextField [(ngModel)]="password" [hint]="Password" secure="true">  
 </TextField>

 <Button [text]="signin'" class="submit-button" (tap)="login(user)">
 </Button>
 <Button [text]="signup'" (tap)="signup(user)"></Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

app.component.tns.html

```
<ActionItem nsRouterLink="/login" ios.position="right" 
android.position="popup">
<Button [text]="'LOGIN' | translate" class="action-item"></Button>
</ActionItem>
```

actually where i need to place the selector(demo-login).any one please help me to solve thid issue. any help will highly appreciable and really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing, but shouldn't the filename `login.component.tns.html` be `login.component.html`?

Comment: nativescript filename is tns.html(angular2seedadvanced)https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced